# Two spin 1/2 particles and measurement of their spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Let's say I have two spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles in a singlet state. I measure the y-spin of the first particle and find it to be $+\frac{\hbar}{2}$. Then how do I calculate the probability that upon the measurement of x-spin of the second particle, I will find it to be  $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$.

I have two conflicting ideas, and somehow I do not seem to be able to figure out which one is right or if they are same.

Attempt 1: I first wrote the singlet state in y-basis.
i.e. $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|{\psi_y^+}\rangle_1 |{\psi_y^-}\rangle_2 -|{\psi_y^-}\rangle_1 $$|{\psi_y^+}\rangle_2 )$

Then, once I measure the y-spin of particle 1 to be $+\frac{\hbar}{2}$, my state of the system will be
$|\psi_{new}\rangle=|{\psi_y^+}\rangle_1 $$|{\psi_y^-}\rangle_2 $. I am very confused as to where to go from here. Now, if I want to measure the x-spin of second particle to be $+\frac{\hbar}{2}$, I guess I should convert $|\psi_{new}\rangle$ into x basis so that it becomes easier, but I do not see how to go about doing that.

Attempt 2: I said: Initially, the system is in state $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|{\psi_z^+}\rangle_1 |{\psi_z^-}\rangle_2 -|{\psi_z^-}\rangle_1 $$|{\psi_z^+}\rangle_2 )$  I want the system to be in the state $|\psi_{new}\rangle = |{\psi_y^+}\rangle_1 |{\psi_x^-}\rangle_2 $. So I expressed $|\psi_{new}\rangle$ in $z$ basis, and then calculated the amplitude by simply doing $\langle\psi_{new}|\psi\rangle$ and then took the modulus square of this to find the probability. However, I believe that this attempt is flawed because I do not think that the measurements are made simultaneously and if I measure spin-y of first particle, I will be projecting my initial state to a new one, and then measure the spin-x in this new state.

So my question is:

Is attempt 2 reasonable or does the doubt I have is correct?

Comment: The first attempt is right, you just have to look up how to change psi in the y basis to the x basis